# Building PL/SQL derived properties on EDT

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to build a function in oracle where 2 dates are compared and depending on it 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' will be returned.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_DATE RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
date1 DATE;
date2 DATE;

BEGIN
 SELECT b_dt INTO date1 FROM table1;

 SELECT max(business_date) INTO date2 FROM table2;

 IF( date1<= date2) THEN
     RETURN 'true';
 ELSE
     RETURN 'FALSE';
 END IF;
END CHECK_DATE;
```

But every time I save this function in SQL Developer, I am getting message as 
`oracle.javatools.db.plsql.parser.AbstractPlSqlBuilder: Building PL/SQL derived properties on EDT`

What exactly this means and why am I getting such message?

Comment: Please post you relevant code.

Comment: This compiles well for me. What is the exact error you are getting? And in compiling or running the function?

Comment: It is working fine with me too but while compiling it give me error oracle.javatools.db.plsql.parser.AbstractPlSqlBuilder: Building PL/SQL derived properties on EDT

Comment: What tool are you using when your get this message?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer 4.5.1.21

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in SQL Developer. Perhaps @thatjeffsmith will drop by :)

Comment: I usually get a few errors as well, when I'm compiling pl/sql. But they are nothing related to what you're doing. Have you checked if indeed you have that function in invalid / error state? Ps: when you compile the function, execute this: Show err